# Get which users the request was sent to Facebook Android

Tags: android, facebook, notifications, facebook-requests

I'm trying to create a application were you can "invite" or tell your friends about it through the Facebook request dialog. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/send-requests/

It works somewhat but one thing I need is to know who the requests were sent TO. How can I do this?

I also have a secondary issue where the request notification only shows up on the users app - not on the desktop page. Anyone know anything about that?

Request code:

```
private void sendRequestDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "!");

        WebDialog requestsDialog = (
            new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(MyPage.this, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                        if (error != null) {
                            if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, 
                                    "Inbjudan avbruten", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, "Nätverksfel, kontrollera din anslutning och försök igen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                            if (requestId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, "Inbjudan skickad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, "Inbjudan avbruten", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }   
                    }



                })
                .build();
        requestsDialog.show();
    }
```

If anyone can help me with this I'm very grateful!
Thank you

Comment: This is a very good idea even i think its not available on Facebook desktop version.

Comment: @rickky Which part are you talking about? The getting the users id's or the sending notifications to desktop because the latter it says in the tutorial (link) it should work.

Comment: i mean your idea is great to know whom we had send friendrequest.

Comment: @rickky Oh sorry let me clarify, it's not a friend request, it's a notification that shows up like "Your name has invited you to this"

Answer (score 3):

Sorry about indentation

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 RequestsDialogBuilder builder = new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(activity, Session.getActiveSession(), params);
 builder.setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

@Override
public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
if (error == null) {
    if (values.containsKey("request")) {

        Set<String> keys = values.keySet();

        for(String key:keys) {
            if(key.contains("to[")) {
                //I know this keys are horrible, but that's how facebook did it
                //Here you have the id's to do something with it
                Logger.d("FACEBOOK", "key " + key + " vlaue " + values.getString(key));                     
            }

        }
    } else {
        if (listener instanceof IFacebookCancelableListener) {
            ((IFacebookCancelableListener) listener).onCancel();
        }
    }
} else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
    if (listener instanceof IFacebookCancelableListener) {
        ((IFacebookCancelableListener) listener).onCancel();
    }
} else {
   //Error
}
}
});
WebDialog dialog = builder.build();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I spent one hour to try to get the key "to" from Bundle values and always get null. Until I see your answer.  Wow, I can't believe it has such ugly "to" key name :|. Again, thank you so much @Moxor :)